# Postgresql: slow delete on records referenced from another table without index

Tags: postgresql

I've table Foo and another table Bar with FK fooId to Foo. The FK has "ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE".
Bar is never queried using fooId, therefore Bar has no index for fooId.

Sometimes however I need to delete manually unreferenced Foo records.
But it takes very long time. I guess it is because Bar need to be sequentially scanned for every Foo to check the FK integrity. Bar is large.

What options do I have?

- Should I add the index that would otherwise not be used and could slow down other operations?
- Is there any kind of DELETE FROM ... "SKIP REFERENCE CHECK" option?
- Could any other "ON DELETE..." on fooId help?
- Anything else I could do to speed up the deletion of unreferenced Foo rows?

Comment: Just add the index, as strongly recommended in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to speed up manual deletions and have access to an account with superuser privilege you could try using

```
ALTER TABLE Bar DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

which will temporarily disable all triggers and FK consistency checks on Bar before deleting and then

```
ALTER TABLE Bar ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

to re-enable them.

**BEWARE**: disabling consistency checks on the FK means you could leave the database in an incosistent state if you were to delete a row from Foo which is still referenced from Bar. Tread carefully.

Just adding the index could also be a sensible option, the write overhead for an additional simple FK btree index isn't usually that relevant, unless inserts on Bar are very frequent, but it really depends on your use case.